# Generate manifest for distfiles, when writing ebuilds for Portage

Tags: package-management, gentoo, portage

I tried to install leiningen from the rebel overlay, however it has a not matching manifest for lein-pkg. So I put it into a local overlay to fix it.
Question:
How can I generate manifest for distfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the overlay dir and run:

```
repoman manifest
```

However, in this case just ignore the broken manifest with

```
emerge --digest ...
```